# Task :capacitor-preferences:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED

Tags: android, capacitor, preferences

Task :capacitor-preferences:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED
....\node_modules@capacitor\preferences\android\src\main\java\com\capacitorjs\plugins\preferences\Preferences.java:3: error: package android.app does not exist
import android.app.Activity;

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you use Java 11 and Gradle 7.4.2 or later.